# Environment vs. application in Elastic Beanstalk AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently started using AWS EBS and was confused as to what environment and application is and what is the difference?

Could I use environment to have a `development` `testing` and `production` environment and then have several applications in each environment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quoting the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.html):

- Application: An Elastic Beanstalk application is a **logical collection** of Elastic Beanstalk components, including environments, versions, and environment configurations. In Elastic Beanstalk an application is conceptually **similar to a folder**.
- Environment: An environment is a **collection of AWS resources** running an application version. Each environment runs only **one application version** at a time, however, you can run the same application version or different application versions in many environments simultaneously.

Back to your question:

> Could I use environment to have a development testing and production environment and then have several applications in each environment?

No. Its the other way around. **One application can have multiple environments**.

For example. If you application is called: `my-first-web-application`, then you could have three independent environments in it:

- prod - environment stable serving real life requests, running stable version of `my-first-web-application` code base.
- dev - development environment when you develop and tests new version of your `my-first-web-application` code base.
- staging - final testing of a new version of your app, before it gets put into production environment.

Comment: Just a side note, I am signed into an old AWS account on awsebcli... do you know what commands I need to do to logout and login to my new one? Thanks again!

Comment: @JannickeTvedt You can use --profile parameter to use different account.

Comment: How exactly would I use this? As you could likely tell from my post, I am new to this stuff!!

Comment: @JannickeTvedt Here is an [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-profile) of how to use profiles.